# External HTTP Images on HTTPS

Tags: ssl

Me and my team seem to be in a little pickle and the chances of me getting a good answer to this question is slim but I have been researching for hours about this topic.

We own a [Webmaster's Forum](https://adminspot.net) that runs under HTTPS, We would like the entire forum to be run under HTTPS But were having difficulties coming up with a solution for external content (mainly images) that are being posted by our users

The images will cause many browsers to display an ugly message regarding the mixture of secure and non-secure content.

Originally the idea was to use an image hosting company that supplies an API and supports SSL, but we cannot find any reasonable ones (Please mentions ones you know)

Storing the images on our server is obviously possible but will eat up our bandwidth so fast it just wouldn't be feasible.

is there anything you guys can suggest that can help me get around this issue, we would be willing to pay a hosting company if the prices are reasonable.

What else I would like to know is if placing non HTTPS content within an Iframe would trigger any errors, as this may be a solution.

Regards

Comment: Sorry....missed the bandwidth bit :/

Comment: No Problem, Thanks for your response none the less.

Answer (score 0):

You may create an https proxy to these images, all it will do is answer a https connection, open a connection to the target image and proxy it to your users' browsers.